# Conditional Dependency or Field Contents

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I’m working on an database, more precisely a **MongoDB** database managed with **mongoose**.

I have a table of `accessories` and they have a `type` that can be “A” or “B”.

They I want to assign the accessory a `subtype` in the following way:

- If the type is “A”, subtype can be “AA” or “AB”.
- If the type is “B”, subtype can be “BA”, “BB” or “BC”.

I don’t want to create a single `subtype` column linked to a single table with all the options “AA” to “BC”. It doesn’t seem clean.

The best approach I’ve thought of is to create two subtype columns (`subtypeA` and `subtypeB`), one is to be linked with subtypes “AA” and “AB” for type “A” or null for type “B” while the other column is to be linked with subtypes “BA”, “BB” and “BC” for type “B” or null for type “A”. The problem with this solution is that it doesn’t seem scalable for more types (“C”, “D”...)

I’m looking for a cleaner solution but I don’t know how to do it with **mongoose** or with other database type.

I need help with the database design.

Comment: MongoDB itself is "schemaless" so you really are talking about "mongoose schema's" here solely as a "client constraint". Please be mindful of your question titles and the tags applied to the question. "Tagging more" may get you more attention, but it may not be the kind of attention you want. Tags only apply to the topic at hand.

Comment: I understand. I thought this could be a general database design issue, that’s the reason of the tags. If I knew how to do this in (for example) SQL I would translate it into a mongoose schema somehow.

Comment: Errm, No it won't! RDBMS And MongoDB are completely different animals, and more to the point "mongoose schema" have their own specific syntax which really is not a general thing. What you are basically looking for is ["Validation Constraints"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) which as explained are implemented functions to ensure that the data you attempt to create actually follows the rules. This sort of thing is different in every database or more specifically every ODM or ORM product.